# How to restore specific directory from tar backup?

Tags: command-line, backup, tar, restore

I had made a tar backup(backup.tar.gz) in Ubuntu 16.04 and I want to restore a specific directory (/usr/share) what should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restore specific directory by following command -

```
tar -xvpzf path_to_backup backup.tar.gz directorypath_you_want_to_extract -C /
```

Note if directory you want to extract is `/home/Downloads` and backup path is `/backup.tar.gz` then remove the beginning `/`.

i.e. `tar -xvpzf backup.tar.gz home/Downloads -C /` and that's it .